# [react-router v4]Do I get to read parent params in a nested Routes pattern?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Route design is:

`/:projectId/`  -> List

`/:projectId/:taskId`  -> Detail

code is:

`<Route path='/:projectId' component={Project} />`

and

```
const Project = ({ match }) => <Switch>
 <Route path={match.url} component={List} />
 <Route path={`${match.url}/:taskId`} component={Detail} />
</Switch>
```

I like nested pattern as it is easier to verify if url is matching or do I need to redirect. But the problem here is I can't read `projectId` inside `<Detail />`and all the children components of it, but some functionality inside does depend on `projectId`. Passing `projectId` as prop all the way down is a solution, but that's the kind of thing I want to get rid of by using react-router in the first place. How do I do it in a right way?

Answer (score 1):

You're close enough! Just the nesting you're doing isn't necessary here.

```
<Switch>
    // Put this <Route /> first otherwise the second will always match.
    <Route path="/:projectId/:taskId" render={props => (
        <h1>{props.match.params.projectId} / {props.match.params.taskId} </h1>
    )} />

    <Route path="/:projectId" render={props => (
        <h1>{props.match.params.projectId}</h1>
    )} />
</Switch>
```

Then for the URL verification, well, usually this check should happen in your `componentWillMount` or the action that will fetch the project / task. You can still here make a redirection with `this.props.replace('/404');`.

Comment: This is a simplified example of the real case. I do find nested style necessary in my case. Better way to solve this is replacing `match.url` with `match.path`, and that's it.